# File-downloading, unzipping and extracting content with a PHP script and tests

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

I am reading the book *Clean Code* by Rob Martin and am trying to write the cleanest possible code.

I wrote this script as part of my project.  Could you please criticise it and let me know how it could be improved?

```
/**
 * File Downloading, Unzipping and extracting Content - PHP
 * 
 * Usage:
 *
 * $fileImporter = new FileImporter($fileReference);
 * $nextRowAsArray = $fileImporter->readFileRowAsArray();
 * 
 * where $fileReference is File Name without Extension
 * $nextRowAsArray is associative Array representing File Entry
 * 
 * If $fileReference.zip is not found, it is downloaded using FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH
 * The archiv $fileReference.zip is automatically extracted whenever needed,
 * and first archiv Entry $file.txt is taken
 *
 * The File $file.txt is expected of the form:
 * 
 * field_name1|field_name2
 * entry1_field1|entry1_field2
 * entry2_field1|entry2_field2
 * ...
 * entryN_field1|entryN_field2
 *
 * Here FILE_ENTRY_SEPARATOR is '|'
 * 
 * Then the returned arrays $nextRowAsArray are subsequently of the form:
 * 
 * array( 'field_name1' => 'entry1_field1', 'field_name2' => 'entry1_field2', )
 * array( 'field_name1' => 'entry2_field1', 'field_name2' => 'entry2_field2', )
 * ...
 * array( 'field_name1' => 'entryN_field1', 'field_name2' => 'entryN_field2', )
 */
class FileImporter {
   private $_download_path = FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH;
   private $_separator = FILE_ENTRY_SEPARATOR;
   private $_fileReference;

   private $_fileHandleCache = null;
   private $_fileHeadRow = array();

   public function __construct ($fileReference) {
      $this->_fileReference = $fileReference;
   }

   public function readFileRowAsArray () {
      $fileHandle = $this->_getCachedOrNewFileHandle();
      $fileEntryArray = $this->_getNextRowAsArray($fileHandle);

      if ( $this->_fileHeadRow ) {
         $keys = $this->_fileHeadRow;
         $values = $fileEntryArray;
      } else {
         $this->_fileHeadRow = $fileEntryArray;
         $keys = $fileEntryArray;
         $values = $this->_getNextRowAsArray($fileHandle);
      }
      return array_combine($keys, $values);
   }

   private function _getCachedOrNewFileHandle () {
      return $this->_fileHandleCache ? $this->_getCachedFileHandle() :  $this->_getNewFileHandle();
   }

   private function _getNextRowAsArray ($fileHandle) {
      $fileNextLine = fgets($fileHandle);
      if ( feof($fileHandle) ) return array();      
      $fileNextLineTrimmed = trim($fileNextLine);
      return explode($this->_separator, $fileNextLineTrimmed);
   }

   private function _getCachedFileHandle () {
      return $this->_fileHandleCache;
   }

   private function _getNewFileHandle () {
      $zipFileName = $this->_getZipFileName();
      if (!file_exists($zipFileName)) $this->_downloadFile($zipFileName);        
      return $this->_unzipAndGetFileHandle($zipFileName);      
   }

   private function _getZipFileName () {
//      return "{$this->_fileReference . '.zip';
      return "{$this->_fileReference}.zip";
   }

   private function _downloadFile ($fileName) {
      $sourceStream = fopen($this->_downloadPath . $fileName, 'r')  or die("Could not download $fileName");
      $destinationStream = fopen($fileName, 'w');
      echo "\n Downloading $fileName\n";
      stream_copy_to_stream($sourceStream, $destinationStream);
   }

   private function _unzipAndGetFileHandle ($zipFileName) {
      $firstZipEntryName = $this->_getFirstZipEntryName($zipFileName);
      if ( !file_exists($firstZipEntryName) ) $this->_ZipExtract($zipFileName);
      $fileHandle = fopen($firstZipEntryName, "rt") or die(" Can't Read File $firstZipEntryName");
      $this->_fileHandleCache = $fileHandle;
      return $fileHandle;
   }

   private function _getFirstZipEntryName ($zipFileName) {
      if ( !file_exists($zipFileName) ) {
         throw new Exception("Attempting to read non-existing Zip File $zipFileName, exitting ....");
      }
      $zipArchiv = zip_open($zipFileName);
      $firstZipEntry = zip_read($zipArchiv);
      $firstZipEntryName = zip_entry_name($firstZipEntry);
      zip_close($zipArchiv);
      return $firstZipEntryName;
   }

   private function _zipExtract ($zipFileName) {
      echo "\n Begin extraction at ", date('r').", file $zipFileName";
      $zipArchiv = new ZipArchive;
      $zipArchiv->open($zipFileName);      
      $zipArchiv->extractTo(".");
      $zipArchiv->close();        
   }
}
```

Here are my tests, which have all passed:

```
/**
 * Testing FileImporter
 */
// case 0: both Zip and Text files exist - creating

function createTextAndZipFiles ($fileRef, $textData) {
   $textFile = $fileRef . '.txt';
   $zipFile = $fileRef . '.zip';
   // creating text file
   file_put_contents($textFile, $textData);
   // creating zip file
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
   $zip->addFile($textFile);
   $zip->close();
}

$testFile = 'file-test';
$testText = <<<EOT
day|year
10|2011
31|1843
EOT;

createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile);
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );

// empty row
$testText = <<<EOT
day|year
10|2011
31|1843

EOT;

createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile);
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['day'] === '10' );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );

// too long row
$testText = <<<EOT
day|year
10|2011|ha
31|1843
EOT;

createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile);
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );

// too short row
$testText = <<<EOT
day|year
2011
31|1843
EOT;

createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile);
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );


// case 1: Zip exists but Text doesn't
createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
// delete Text
unlink($testFile . '.txt');

$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile);
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );


// case 2: Text exists but Zip doesn't
// faking download by using local subdirectory
// creating subdirectory 'test'
$subdirName = 'test';
// make sure directory exists and is not a file
if ( file_exists($subdirName) ) {
   if ( !is_dir($subdirName) ) {
      unlink($subdirName);
      mkdir($subdirName);
   }
} else {
   mkdir($subdirName);
}

createTextAndZipFiles($testFile, $testText);
// now move zipfile into the subdirectory
$zipFileName = $testFile . '.zip';
rename($zipFileName, $subdirName . '/' . $zipFileName);

$importer_test = new FileImporter($testFile, $subdirName . '/');
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray === array() );
$rowArray = $importer_test->readFileRowAsArray();
assert( $rowArray['year'] === '1843' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the book you mention, although it looks good so I might buy it and have a read.

A few things for me

There are echo statements in the code, I am assuming that is for debugging and you are going to remove them.

In a couple of places you use die(),  and then elsewhere you throw an exception. 
Personally I would throw exceptions and let it bubble up to somewhere that can handle them properly.

Your class is called fileImporter, but it also has a download aspect to it as well. I am wondering if fileDownloader should be separated out.

You have a private getter function

```
   private function _getCachedFileHandle () {
      return $this->_fileHandleCache;
   }
```

Which I find unusual, I normally only use publicly accessible getters.

```
// It is just as easy to use this internally 
$f= $this->_fileHandleCache;

// as it is to use, so why make it more complex
$f = $this->_getCachedFileHandle();
```

Code reuse, when I design stuff I only create a separate method if I can reuse the same code, or due to it's complexity/size of the function it is best to break it into smaller parts to make it more readable.

```
// this bit of code is only called once and is simple, so it could be included inline
public function readFileRowAsArray () {
    $fileHandle = $this->_getCachedOrNewFileHandle();

// like this
public function readFileRowAsArray () {
    $fileHandle = $this->_fileHandleCache ? $this->_getCachedFileHandle() :  $this->_getNewFileHandle();
```

There also appears to be no way to overide these private variables which are set to constant values.

```
class FileImporter {
    private $_download_path = FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH;
    private $_separator = FILE_ENTRY_SEPARATOR;
```

If that is the case, then why re-declare then, why not use FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH and FILE_ENTRY_SEPARATOR directly in your code

If you do want to allow them to be overridden, then you could extend your constructor

```
public function __construct ($fileReference, $download_path = FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH, $separator = FILE_ENTRY_SEPARATOR) {
    $this->_fileReference = $fileReference;
    $this->_download_path = $download_path ;
    $this->_separator = $separator ;

}
```

Hope that gives you some ideas to think about